# How to get value from a drop-down menu in HTML to php

Tags: php, html

I have a drop down list as shown bellow. If a user select a certain item from the list, I would like to capture it in my php code and print it out. Following code can't capture that value and always print out "Doesn't work". I am new to html/php and any help would be appreciated.

```
<select id="selectype" name="cards">
<option value="WorkOrder">Work Order</option>
<option value="FirstName">First Name</option>
</select>

<?php
if (cards.value == "WorkOrder")
   echo "WorkOrder selected";
else if (card.value == "FirstName")
   echo "FirstName selected";
else
   echo "Doesn't work";
?>
```

Comment: Please understand the basics of php before asking questions here.

* you are missing the $ sign for variables

* selecting somthing cant trigger php code unless you are submitting a form and using the values of $_GET and $_POST

Comment: You might want to start with an introductory tutorial on PHP.  `cards` and `card` are different identifiers, they're not PHP variables (PHP variables begin with a `$`), and you don't define them anywhere or initialize them to posted form values from something like `$_POST`.  Honestly, it shouldn't even be printing out `"Doesn't work"` because the code you've written isn't even parseable.

Comment: You can literally google search your title and you'd have the answer. Instead you wasted potentially 5 minutes of your life waiting for something you could have done in seconds :D google-fu, sir. Google-fu.

Comment: I just... really am... wot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your HTML in a self-submitting form..

```
<form action="" method="POST">

    <select id="selectype" name="cards">
        <option value="WorkOrder">Work Order</option>
        <option value="FirstName">First Name</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" />

</form>

<?php

    $cards = $_POST['cards'];

    if ($cards == "WorkOrder")
       echo "WorkOrder selected";

    else if ($cards == "FirstName")
       echo "FirstName selected";

    else
       echo "Doesn't work";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me with an example. Now I understand the POST concept and how to access it via php.

Answer (score 0):

You must use your element name in your PHP code. At first, you must create a form, which will send your variable into your PHP code. Or if you dont wanna use form, you can perform this via jQuery, but is more difficult.

You have got dropdown, which is called `cards` and it can contain only 1 value, so I was edited your code bellow. Now you will get value from element called `cards` and then with your IF's (switch will be better, maybe) you can identify, what is set as value.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <select id="selectype" name="cards">
    <option value="WorkOrder">Work Order</option>
    <option value="FirstName">First Name</option>
  </select>
</form>

<?php
$cards = $_POST['cards'];
if ($cards == "WorkOrder")
   echo "WorkOrder selected";
else if ($cards == "FirstName")
   echo "FirstName selected";
else
   echo "Doesn't work";
?>
```

Comment: yes, its my fault ... I forgot to add `form` tag :/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the value of an HTML-field in your php this way. When you see the site appear, the php is long gone. php is being executed on the server and after execution the page is being rendered and "put" on the browser.

So, if you want to have the value of a field you have to "put" this value "back" to the server. You need at least this:

```
<form action="yourphpcode.php" method="post">
  <select id="selectype" name="cards">
    <option value="WorkOrder">Work Order</option>
    <option value="FirstName">First Name</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

And a submit button, would also help.

In your "yourphpcode.php" you can access the values like this:

```
<?php
  $cards = $_POST['cards']
?>
```

... and you should really read a beginners tutorial. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST['cards'] == "WorkOrder")
   echo "WorkOrder selected";
else if ($_REQUEST['cards'] == "FirstName")
   echo "FirstName selected";
else
   echo "Doesn't work";
?>
```

Comment: If the form method is clearly defined, use it like so. `$_REQUEST` is better used when you don't know the request type that will be incoming.